# I get a runtime error when attempting to connect to Snowflake using VBA ADODB

Tags: excel, vba, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, adodb

I am trying to connect to Snowflake within VBA and get a runtime error: Automation error, unspecified error. Any idea what could be causing it? I do have the ActiveX package installed. In the debugging I do see the problem is when the connection string attempts to open.

```
Sub selectSnow()
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrQuery As String


ConnectionString = "DRIVER={SnowflakeDSIIDriver};SERVER=XXXXXX.snowflakecomputing.com;" & _
                               "DATABASE=XXXXX;SCHEMA=XXXXXX;" & _
                                 "ROLE=XXXXX;UID=XXXXXX;" & _
                                "PROXY = http://proxy:port;Authenticator = externalbrowser"
                       
cnn.Open ConnectionString
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you aware that there is already an excel add-in?

Comment: The Excel add-in mentioned by @Sorceri is Excelerator which may be downloaded at https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/Excelerator. Review the source code there to learn more about the required VBA code.

Comment: Thanks I have read over it. I am looking to try to understand if there is a way to do it without Excel without the add-in installation.